# Excel VBA .Navigate error Object Required

Tags: excel, vba

The below script is giving me a 424 Object Required error. I have tested the output of rCell.Value and it will generate a URL, however, it will cause the error when it tries to navigate to it. If I put a string to replace the rCell.Value the code works fine. and will execute the URL.

```
Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim MyURL As String
Dim rCell As Range
Dim rRng As Range

Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A6")


 For Each rCell In rRng

    Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
    MyBowser.Silent = True
    MyBowser.navigate = rCell.Value
    MyBowser.Visible = True
```

Do I need to convert that variable into a string?

Comment: Do the first and last cells contain " " marks to go around rCell.Value?

Comment: I have just tried adding the " " marks, I have tried each cell wrapped in them and the first cell having the entry " and the last having the end " and still receive that error.

Comment: Have you tried `MyBowser.navigate = CStr(rCell.Value)`? Also `rCell.Text` may work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did to make it work, I had to add a new variable and then remove the = between navigate and the variable.

```
Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim MyURL As String
Dim rCell As Range
Dim rRng As Range

Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A6")


 For Each rCell In rRng
    MyURL = rCell.Value
    Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
    MyBowser.Silent = True
    MyBowser.navigate MyURL
    MyBowser.Visible = True
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like: 
`Dim x as String 
x = """" 
MyBowser.navigate = x & rCell.Value & x`